# Is it possible to access an Apple Time Capsule over the internet?

Tags: time-machine, time-capsule

I'd like to be able to continue backing things up even when I'm not in the office, so if it's easy to access it over the internet, I'd like to set this up.

I'm using OSX Lion.

Answer (score 0):

No, this isn't possible, for a variety of reasons, the biggest of which is the unknown speed of your connections when you're not on the Time Capsule's network.  It would be far too unreliable and slow in almost every case for it to be worth it, so Apple doesn't allow it for the 0.5% of the users who might be willing to tolerate it or make it work.

You **can** use iCloud to access your Time Capsule remotely, but I do not think you can use that as a backup destination.

Comment: Do you know how I can use iCloud in that fashion? iCloud is configured on the Time Capsule, but when I log in to iCloud I don't see it (but it might not be obvious).

Comment: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3699096  You have to access it from the sidebar in Finder, under the Shared header.  You should see your time capsule, even when you're not on your network.